# Uneven box shadow with CSS3 / HTML5?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an uneven shadow effect for a website, please see an example below of what I need to achieve:

[image]

Unfortunately I don't think this can be done with CSS3, to my knowledge the box-shadow property can only be used to create evenly spread shadows.

However, my knowledge of CSS3/HTML5 isn't great so I was wondering if anybody knows of anyway to achieve this without resorting to images/extra div's/relative & absolute positioning which I would rather avoid?

Comment: What you could do is put a square div behind this one, use transform to rotate it, and apply the box-shadow to that.

Comment: Do you have any idea if I could accomplish that with .some-element:after (that way I can avoid littering the HTML with style related div's) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the closest what I've came to your image preview, you can wrap these in a positioned relative div and set the positions accordingly

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xKWj4/)

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="shadow"></div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 50px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    z-index: 1;
}


.shadow {
    -ms-transform: rotate(2deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transform: rotate(2deg); /* Opera */
    -moz-transform: rotate(2deg); /* Firefox */
    box-shadow: 0 6px 16px -6px black;
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 225px;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I also managed to use pseudo elements to eliminate the need for the extra div: http://jsfiddle.net/8XN8j/ I'll do some tweaking but just this is pretty much just what I was looking for!

Comment: @SeanDunwoody you welcome :) just be sure of 1 thing, I made it in a hurry as I need to leave so wrap these inside a div with `position: relative;` and 1 more thing is it's CSS3 so be sure it supports all browsers, ofcourse I've added all proprietary CSS but than too ;)

Answer (score 3):

The best i could come up with was placing a pseudo-element behind your div:

```
div::after{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    transform:rotate(5deg);
    box-shadow:1px 5px 50px #444;
    z-index:-1;
}​
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M7ccq/2/)**

I guess you want to play a little with the values and try to get as close as possible to your original.

Comment: Cool, hadn't thought of using transforms on the element to try and manipulate the shadow! I'll mess around with the values and see if I can get what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can with a few properties. i.e:

html:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="shadow-phantom">
  </div>
</div>​
```

css:

```
.main {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#e1e1e1;
  margin:10px auto;
}  


.shadow-phantom {
 -webkit-border-radius: 12px 110px 20px 25px;
 border-radius: 12px 110px 20px 25px;
 margin: -4px 0px 0px -0px;
 -moz-background-clip: padding; 
 -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; background-clip: padding-box;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 10px 0px #AAA; 
      box-shadow: 7px 7px 10px 0px #AAA; 
    width:90px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(5.5deg);  
 -moz-transform: rotate(5.5deg);  
  -ms-transform: rotate(5.5deg);  
   -o-transform: rotate(5.5deg);  
      transform: rotate(5.5deg); 
  }​
```

check this fiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/wandarkaf/MKV4Q/

Comment: i wonder 1) wh some people post a nearly duplicated answer 20minutes after 2 other people 2) why you included background-clip - it has absolutely no impact on current markup 3) why you didn't use a pseudo element but instead clutter the markup with an additional useless element.

Comment: cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: This argument is invalid in every case: pseudo-elements are supported in every browser which can handle transforms and box-shadows and background-clip has absolutely no impact on this scenario.

Comment: the use of -moz-background-clip is useful if you don't want a bg color from leaking outside the border.

Comment: You mean **[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/MKV4Q/1/)**? Believe me, it is of no use, since you did not specify any border on your example...